# Stop rotation of the Cube for specific time in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to stop a rotating cube for specific time in three js. This pause/stop duration can vary from 1 to 30 seconds. Lets say cube should stop on each face for 5 seconds and then move on to the next face. Cube is rotating horizontally i.e. **only** `"style1"`. Here is my function that is controlling rotation of the cube.

```
function animate() {
    var time = new Date().getTime();

    var rotation_speed_controling_value = 5000;

    if (parseInt(_this.rotation_speed) == 0) {
        time = 0;
    } else {
        // Handling Rotation Speed Here
        rotation_speed_controling_value = rotation_speed_controling_value - (parseInt(_this.rotation_speed) * 700)
        // console.log(rotation_speed_controling_value);
    }

    _this.scene.traverse(function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof THREE.Object3D) {
            switch (obj.name) {
                case "scene-1-lambert-cube":
                    obj.position.set(0, 0, 0);

                    // Rotation styles

                    // Here we are handling styles of cube rotatioon by providing different combination of X,Y,Z

                    switch (_this.rotation_style) {
                        case "style1":
                            obj.rotation.x = 0;
                            // obj.rotation.y = (time / (rotation_speed_controling_value+(parseInt(_this.stop_duration) * 1000)));
                            obj.rotation.y = (time / (rotation_speed_controling_value + (parseInt(_this.stop_duration) * 1000)));
                            obj.rotation.z = 0;
                            break;
                        case "style2":
                            obj.rotation.x = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            obj.rotation.y = 0;
                            obj.rotation.z = 0;
                            break;
                        case "style3":
                            obj.rotation.x = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            obj.rotation.y = 0;
                            obj.rotation.z = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            break;
                        case "style4":
                            obj.rotation.x = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            obj.rotation.y = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            obj.rotation.z = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value);
                            break;
                        case "style5":
                            obj.rotation.x = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            obj.rotation.y = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            obj.rotation.z = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            break;
                        case "style6":
                            obj.rotation.x = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            obj.rotation.y = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            obj.rotation.z = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            break;
                        case "style7":
                            obj.rotation.x = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            obj.rotation.y = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            obj.rotation.z = (time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            break;
                        case "style8":
                            obj.rotation.x = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value - 200);
                            obj.rotation.y = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            obj.rotation.z = -(time / rotation_speed_controling_value + 200);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < _this.nbScenes; i++) {
                if (obj.name.startsWith("scene-" + i)) {
                    obj.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(i * _this.sceneDistance, 0, 0));
                }
            }

            // move camera if in transition
            if (_this.sceneTransitionT0 !== undefined && _this.sceneTransitionV0 !== undefined) {
                // parameter between 0 and 1, ease-in speed profile
                var s = (t - _this.sceneTransitionT0) / _this.sceneTransitionDuration;
                if (s <= 1) {
                    // V = s * V1 + (1-s) * V0
                    s = Math.sqrt(1 - (s - 1) * (s - 1)); // ease-in speed profile
                    var v = new THREE.Vector3();
                    v.copy(_this.sceneTransitionV0);
                    v.multiplyScalar(1 - s);
                    var w = _this.cameraPositionsForScene(_this.currentScene);
                    w.multiplyScalar(s);
                    camera.position.addVectors(v, w);
                } else {
                    _this.sceneTransitionT0 = undefined;
                    _this.sceneTransitionV0 = undefined;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    _this.renderer.render(_this.scene, camera);

    // let the browser decide the tempo

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```